# Missing parts on Beautiful Soup results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve few `<p>` tags in the following html code. Here is only the part of it

```
<td class="eelantext">
    <a class="fBlackLink"></a>
    <center></center>
    <span> … </span><br></br>
    <table width="402" vspace="5" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" 
        border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="Left">
    <tbody> … </tbody></table>
      <!--edstart-->
    <p> … </p>
    <p> … </p>
    <p> … </p>
    <p> … </p>
    <p> … </p>
</td>
```

You can find the webpage [here](http://www.ekathimerini.com/4dcgi/_w_articles_wsite1_1_04/09/2013_517147)

My Python code is the following

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
div = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'eelantext'})
print div
text = div.find_all('p')
```

But the text variable is empty and if I print the div variable, I have exactly the same html from above except the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

BeautifulSoup can use [different parsers to handle HTML input](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). The HTML input here is a little broken, and the default `HTMLParser` parser doesn't handle it very well.

Use the [`html5lib` parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib) instead:

```
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html').find('td', attrs={'class': 'eelantext'}).find_all('p'))
0
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml').find('td', attrs={'class': 'eelantext'}).find_all('p'))
0
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib').find('td', attrs={'class': 'eelantext'}).find_all('p'))
22
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work perfect. I had to install html5lib first, but now works. :)

Comment: pip install --upgrade html5lib