# JavaScript rendered web page scraping with PyQt

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, pyqt4

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html


# Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
# This step is important.Converting QString to Ascii for lxml to process
archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.encode('utf-8')))
print(archive_links)
```

I got that script from [this page](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/).I had to change the result.toAscii() to result.encode('utf-8)

When i run this script it returns:

```
> <Element div at 0x7f98226af458>
```

Im not pro in Python and i dont know exactly what is that mean.Is it a kind of stored information?
It suppose to return the links in the webpage.

After that,i added for loop like this:

```
for link in archive_links:
   print(link)
```

It returns:

```
> <Element p at 0x7f09a14d3408> <Element meta at 0x7f09a14d34a8>
> <Element meta at 0x7f09a14d34f8> <Element meta at 0x7f09a14d3408>
> <Element meta at 0x7f09a14d34a8> <Element meta at 0x7f09a14d34f8>
> <Element link at 0x7f09a14d3408> <Element link at 0x7f09a14d34a8>
> <Element title at 0x7f09a14d34f8> <Element style at 0x7f09a14d3408>
> <!-- Bootstrap core CSS --> <Element link at 0x7f09a14d34f8> <!--
> Custom styles for this template --> <Element link at 0x7f09a14d3408>
> <!-- Fonts from Google Fonts --> <Element link at 0x7f09a14d34a8> <!--
> HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media
> queries --> <!--[if lt IE 9]>\n\t  <script
> src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>\n\t
> <script
> src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>\n\t<![endif]-->
> <!-- Fixed navbar --> <Element div at 0x7f09a14d34a8> <Element div at
> 0x7f09a14d3408> <Element div at 0x7f09a14d34f8> <!-- /container -->
> <!-- Bootstrap core
> JavaScript\n\t================================================== -->
> <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
> <Element script at 0x7f09a14d34f8> <Element script at 0x7f09a14d3408>
> <Element script at 0x7f09a14d34a8> <Element script at 0x7f09a14d34f8>
```

Also,can we do this with PyQt5 easily?I'm open to any kind of suggestion.
Thank you.

Edit:**This edit is relevant to JS scraping topic.But its about scraping another [site](http://oil-price.net/) and with different technique.**
I checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654961/why-is-beautifulsoup-not-finding-a-specific-table-class) before create this topic.I dont understand what this code does:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find("div",{"id":"cntPos"}).find("table",{"class":"cntTb"}).tbody.find_all("tr")[1].find("td",{"class":"cntBoxGreyLnk"}) is None

> True
```

Returns True.What i did with this code is:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://oil-price.net').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find("div",{"id":"cntPos"}).find("table",{"class":"cntTb"}).tbody.find_all("tr")[1].find("td",{"class":"cntBoxGreyLnk"})
print(soup)
```

But this code doesnt return dynamic oil prices.It returns this:

```
> /usr/bin/python3.5
> /home/dogus/PycharmProjects/Recipes/bsdoesntfindjs.py <td
> class="cntBoxGreyLnk" rowspan="2" valign="top"> <script
> src="http://www.oil-price.net/COMMODITIES/gen.php?lang=en"
> type="text/javascript"> </script> <noscript> To get live <a
> href="http://www.oil-price.net/dashboard.php?lang=en#COMMODITIES">gold,
> oil and commodity price</a>, please enable Javascript. </noscript>
> <br/> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="b11"> <tbody> <tr>
> <td colspan="3" height="15"> <a
> href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Oil-pricenet-OilPriceTodayAndTomorrow"
> style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; "><img border="0"
> src="/pics/feed-icon.gif"/>  Subscribe to RSS</a><br/> <hr/> <br/>
> <form action="http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/emailverify"
> method="post"
> onsubmit="window.open('http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/emailverifySubmit?feedId=1678900',
> 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true"
> style="border:0px solid #ccc;padding:8px;text-align:center; font-size:
> 12px; font-weight: normal;" target="popupwindow"> <p style="font-size:
> 14px; font-weight: bold;"><img border="0" height="40"
> src="/index_files/email_40.png" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"
> widht="40"/> Receive our FREE<br/>Oil Intelligence Newsletter:
> <br/><span style="font-size:11px; font-weight:normal;">(We don't
> spam)</span> </p><p><input name="email" style="width:140px"
> type="text"/></p><input name="url" type="hidden"
> value="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~e?ffid=1678900"/><input
> name="title" type="hidden" value="Oil-price.net - Oil Price, Today and
> Tomorrow"/><input name="loc" type="hidden" value="en_US"/><input
> type="submit" value="Subscribe"/></form> </td> </tr><tr><td
> colspan="3"> <hr/><br/> <div class="b11"> <strong style="white-space:
> nowrap;">oil-price.net is available in</strong> <br/> <br/> </div>
> </td></tr> <tr> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=fr"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_fr.png" width="54"/><br/>            Français </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=en"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_en.png" width="54"/><br/>            English </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=zh"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_zh.png" width="54"/><br/>            中国 </a> </td> </tr>
> <tr> <td colspan="3" height="15"></td> </tr> <tr> <td
> style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=it"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_it.png" width="54"/><br/>            Italiano </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=th"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_th.png" width="54"/><br/>            ภาษาไทย </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=ar"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_ar.png" width="54"/><br/>            العربيه </a> </td>
> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="3" height="15"></td> </tr> <tr> <td
> style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=nl"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_nl.png" width="54"/><br/>            Nederland </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=pt"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_pt.png" width="54"/><br/>            Português </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=ko"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_ko.png" width="54"/><br/>            한국어 </a> </td> </tr>
> <tr> <td colspan="3" height="15"></td> </tr> <tr> <td
> style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=ja"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_ja.png" width="54"/><br/>            日本語 </a> </td> <td
> style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=ru"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_ru.png" width="54"/><br/>            Русскийязык </a>
> </td> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=id"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_id.png" width="54"/><br/>            Bahasa
> <br/>Indonesia </a> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="3" height="15"></td>
> </tr> <tr> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=es"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_es.png" width="54"/><br/>            Espanol </a> </td>
> <td style="padding-right: 15px;" valign="middle"> <a
> href="/index.php?lang=de"><img border="0" height="21"
> src="index_files/lng_de.png" width="54"/><br/>            Deutsch </a> </td>
> </tr></tbody></table> </td>
```

Another user recommends to use PyV8 but it seems to me that it is a too old library to use.Last update was in 2012.Should i learn it? Or should i stick with PyQt4? or 5?

Comment: Maybe Phantom / Slimer / CasperJS?

Comment: I did a search,and i guess they are a bit more difficult to use.
CasperJS in particular seemed more complex since i dont know JS.
I guess i have to find an ebook that shows JS page scraping in Python.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I do not see the question, just two different solutions. What was the output from your beautiful soup code? It seems like the easiest solution. They have a [good doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: First output doesnt return the links in the page.
Second output doesnt return the dynamic oil prices.
I dont understand why,at all.

Comment: What do you want to get? HTML data/plain text from selector/iframe or an image?

Comment: Oil prices would be enough.It would be nice if it could give me: 
WTI Crude Oil : $45.69
Brent Crude Oil:$46.86
Im not interested in oil prices spesificaly.I just want to learn how to get that information.So i can use the technique in other things.

Such as,i cant get the current weather report from this site too:
http://www.mgm.gov.tr/?il=Istanbul&ilce=Bahcelievler
When i use bs4 it doesnt return the current temperature,like 16.8C.Its kinda hidden from bs4.

Comment: @Sapientia That is okay. The first time, you are just asking for html and that is what you get, the complete html. You can try to loop through that to get your data. In the second solution, it will be great if you can tell us what do you get instead of your required data. It feels to me that since you used the work "dynamic", your required data is not part of the first html at all i.e. loaded dynamically using ajax. In that case, the best method is to observe the traffic to see which http request brings your data. You might be lucky and get a json or xml.

Comment: @Sapientia Try to use my solution: http://pastebin.com/557rW3Zg Just execute js in the console of the browser.

Comment: @Igor Awesome but i dont know JS :( is that CasperJS?
I need to learn how to get that by using Python.
Im planing to learn JS but i guess i should be expert in Python first.

Comment: @Sapientia Now you have `js code` and also `CasperJS` script. Try to execute that code in the `console` of your browser (Above the `CasperJS` section).