# BeautifulSoup to find text inside the table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<head> ... </head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Something really cool here<h2>
        <div class="section mylist">
            <table id="list_1" class="table">
                <thead> ... not important <thead>
                <tr id="blahblah1"> <td> ... </td> </tr> 
                <tr id="blah2"> <td> ... </td> </tr> 
                <tr id="bl3"> <td> ... </td> </tr> 
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now there are four occurrences of this `div` in my html file, each table content is different and each `h2` text is different. Everything else is relatively the same. What I've been able to do so far is extract out the parent of each `h2` - however, now I am not sure how to extract out each `tr` where in then, I can extract out the `td` that I really need.

Here is the code I've written so far...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myhtml.html'), 'html.parser')

currently_watching = soup.find('h2', text='Something really cool here')
parent = currently_watching.parent
```

Comment: Take a look at [pyquery](https://github.com/gawel/pyquery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest finding the parent `div`, which *actually* encloses the table, and then search for all `td` tags. Here's how you'd do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myhtml.html'), 'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', class_='section mylist')    
for td in div.find_all('td'):
    print(td.text)
```

Comment: For some reason, it gives me a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` in the first line of that for loop

Comment: @user1883614 It should be `find_all`. Sorry.

Comment: It's not printing anything - I double checked what I've provided above and it matches the code that i have...

Comment: @user1883614 That is disappointing. Try `print(td.string)` and then `print(td.content)`, whichever works. One of them should. Let me know which works.

Comment: So I tried doing `print len(div.find_all('tr'))` which gave me a 0 and I've been looking online for some other code examples but I can't seem to figure out why it won't read it.

Comment: @user1883614 Weird. I tried it with your input and it works for me. Try perhaps, `open('myhtml.html').read()` instead? Also, you should be looking for `td`, not `tr`.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but the div code is inside a `body` tag which is inside `html`. Updated the code from above

Comment: It makes no difference, because it worked for me. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Searched around a bit and realized that it was my parser that was causing the issue. I installed lxml and everything works fine now.

[Why is BeautifulSoup not finding a specific table class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654961/why-is-beautifulsoup-not-finding-a-specific-table-class)